# Unable to install coc-clangd

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc, clangd

When I use the command `:CocInstall clangd` to install coc-clangd, it will throw the following error:

```
[Coc.nvim] Error on install coc-clangd: AggregateError
```

Why do I get this error?

OS: Archlinux
Editor: NeoVim v0.9.2
Plugin manager: vim-plug
node: 20.8.0
npm: 10.2.0

Comment: Did you [install clandg](https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#installing-clangd) first?

Comment: Has `https://registry.npmjs.org` been blocked by Firewall ? Put `coc.nvim:registry={URL}` to the end of ~/.npmrc, and {URL} need to be replaced by a reachable mirror url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for coc-clangd to be installed you need first to [install clangd](https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#installing-clangd) itself.